# angularjs split comma seperate in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

**ng-repeat display the comma separated to one by one**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.obj = [ { "name": "Operational Current Ie AC-15 at 230V", "displayType": "RadioButton", "options": "10A" }, { "name": "Size", "displayType": "RadioButton", "options": "S00" }, { "name": "Coil Voltage", "displayType": "RadioButton", "options": "24V AC, 110V AC, 230V AC, 24V DC, 110V DC, 220V DC" }, { "name": "Contacts", "displayType": "RadioButton", "options": "4NO, 3NO+1NC, 2NO+2NO" } ];
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="value in obj">
<li>{{ value.name }}</li>
<li>{{ value.displayType }} </li>
<li>{{ value.options }}</li><!-- this should be splitted and display one one like this
24v ac
110v ac
230v ac
24v ac
-->
</ul>
 
</div>
```

> the list should separate like this

1. 24v ac
2. 110v ac

Comment: what have you tried? did you check the ng-options docs? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: i nedd to implement in list how can i use ng-option

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask read the documentation here on how to ask a good question, this would go some way to explain the downvote. There is a lack of context to your code, but you should also include some examples of what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add This code in your JS File

```
            $scope.variantAttributeses = [
                {"name": "Operational Current Ie AC-15 at 230V", "displayType": "RadioButton", "options": "10A"},
                {"name": "Size", "displayType": "RadioButton", "options": "S00"},
                {"name": "Coil Voltage", "displayType": "RadioButton", "options": "24V AC, 110V AC, 230V AC, 24V DC, 110V DC, 220V DC"},
                {"name": "Contacts", "displayType": "RadioButton", "options": "4NO, 3NO+1NC, 2NO+2NO"}
            ];

            function split() {
             $scope.newArray = [];
             angular.forEach($scope.variantAttributeses, function (value) {
                value["NewOptions"] = [];
                angular.forEach(value.options.split(","), function (v1) {
                    value["NewOptions"].push(v1);
                });
                $scope.newArray.push(value);
            });
        }
       split();
```

Add this code in your HTML File

```
<span data-ng-repeat="status in newArray">
    <span data-ng-repeat="optionAry in status.NewOptions">
        <span class="badge" data-ng-bind="optionAry"></span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Output display like below
[image]

Comment: i need to split the option values and display it seperately

Comment: @GopiRain I have Updated my answer, Please Check.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for?

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="value in obj">
<li>{{ value.name }}</li>
<li>{{ value.displayType }} </li>
<li>{{ value.options }}</li>
</ul>
 
</div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.obj = [ { "name": "Operational Current Ie AC-15 at 230V", "displayType": "RadioButton", "options": "10A" }, { "name": "Size", "displayType": "RadioButton", "options": "S00" }, { "name": "Coil Voltage", "displayType": "RadioButton", "options": "24V AC, 110V AC, 230V AC, 24V DC, 110V DC, 220V DC" }, { "name": "Contacts", "displayType": "RadioButton", "options": "4NO, 3NO+1NC, 2NO+2NO" } ];
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need to separate the options, then you need to use some form of substring to cut out the options.

So, for example, this is what I would do with raw JS to get the first option for coil voltage.

```
const optionOne = variantAttributeses[2].options.substring(0,5):
```

The value optionOne should return `24 AC`.